# Laravel Error: "Property [siblings] does not exist on this collection instance"

Tags: laravel, eloquent

**I want to get list of siblings each student has**

**Controller:**

```
public function show($id)
{
    $finddata = Student::orderBy('id', 'asc')->get();
    $BS = Student::with('Family')->get();

    return View('students.list' ,compact('finddata','BS'));
}
```

**Student Model: foreign key: family_id**

```
public function family()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(family::class, 'family_id');
}

public function siblings()
{
    return $this->belongsTo("Family", "family_id");
}
```

**Family Model:**

```
public function siblings()
{
    return $this->hasMany("Student");
}
```

**View:**

```
@foreach($finddata as $record)
    {{$finddata->studentname}}
@endforeach

@foreach($BS->siblings as sibling)    
{{sibling->name}}
@endforeach
```

> Error: "Property [siblings] does not exist on this collection instance. (View: \views\students\list.blade.php)"

Comment: `siblings` is a method on your `Family` model, but you're calling it on your student. Go on with something like `$BS->family->siblings->where('id', '!=', $BS->id)`

Comment: @D.Petrov  can you please elaborate?